# Reach Past a Domain and Grab File from Host

Tags: html, src

Is it possible to reference an image from the web host using `../images/img.png` if the index is on the domain folder?

```
  index.html                     img.png
      |                             |
  domain.com                     images (folder)
      |                             |
       -------------Host------------
```

Comment: What is the direct path to the image.. domain.com/images/img.png? or does it go 1 more level back?

Comment: @Bijan The images folder is outside of the domain folder but still within the host folder. For exsample on your computer (Win) if the C folder was the domain "http://www.C.com" (path "This PC\C\index.html"), the image is located in "This PC\Documents\img.png".

Comment: I'm thinking this is probably not possable.

Comment: In that case, no it is probably not possible. Run [This](http://codepad.org/h9Nj7NiY) to get full directory path and then see if you are able to access things beyond the scope of domain.com